# Work done in an Adiabatic process

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, work, adiabatic

I was reading [this](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook.php?kech1=6-7) chapter, and am confused with the concept provided under heading WORK (on page 162). The term "adiabatic" as I understand it, involves,**absolutely no exchange of energy between surrounding and system**. But *by introducing a rotating paddle (electrically powered or otherwise) or a heater coil*, *we are actually introducing energy (in this case, electrical) from the surrounding*. How can, then, this process be considered adiabatic?

Comment: I've always taken this to just mean that heat doesn't leak out of the system. So no "unintentional" removal of energy from the system. Of course, you could just consider the paddle motor/heater coil and its battery to be part of the adiabetic system too.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 2):

> “ The term "adiabatic" as I understand it, involves, absolutely no
> exchange of energy between surrounding and system”

That is incorrect. Adiabatic only means no energy transfer in the form of heat. It does not include energy transfer in the form of work. Work includes boundary or $PdV$ work, paddle work, electrical work, etc..

Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. For a process to be adiabatic, either the boundary between the system and surroundings is thermally insulated (for example insulated cylinder walls) or the process is carried out so fast that there is no time for heat to transfer.

A rotating paddle is generally considered a mechanical work input. In fact it’s called “paddle work” or “stirrer work”.  An electrical heater coil is a peculiar case and may be considered as either heat or electrical work depending on its location and the definition of the system and its boundary relative to the coil. However it’s no so important how you define it as long as you properly take its energy transfer into account when applying the first law.

Hope this helps.